# Combine all permutations of lists within a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Given the initial dictionary

`c = {'c': {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 4]}}`

I want to generate a dictionary that has all possible permutations, without explicitly calling the indices

Expected output:

```
c = {'c0': {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
     'c1': {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
     'c2': {'a': 1, 'b': 4},
     'c3': {'a': 2, 'b': 2},
     'c4': {'a': 2, 'b': 3},
     'c5': {'a': 2, 'b': 4},
     'c6': {'a': 3, 'b': 2},
     'c7': {'a': 3, 'b': 3},
     'c8': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}
```

What I've tried (it is not pretty but I can't think straight right now):

```
p = {}

for i, j in c.items():

  for k in j.keys():
    xxx = 0
    for v in j[k]:
      if i + str(xxx) in p.keys():
        p[i + str(xxx)][k] = v
      else:
        p[i + str(xxx)] = {}
        p[i + str(xxx)][k] = v
      xxx +=1
```

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: Essentially to create a json file that will be return more specific results rather than the entire collection, where each has its own ID

Comment: Results of what? What ID?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product as pt
c = {'c': {'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b': [2, 3, 4]}}
new_c = {f'{a}{i}':dict(zip(b.keys(), k)) for a, b in c.items() for i, k in enumerate(pt(*b.values()))}
```

Output:

```
 {'c0': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
  'c1': {'a': 1, 'b': 3}, 
  'c2': {'a': 1, 'b': 4}, 
  'c3': {'a': 2, 'b': 2}, 
  'c4': {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, 
  'c5': {'a': 2, 'b': 4}, 
  'c6': {'a': 3, 'b': 2}, 
  'c7': {'a': 3, 'b': 3}, 
  'c8': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}
```

Comment: this solves the problem, but holy cow is that solution unreadable. how is anyone supposed to read that and understand? that is why I am down voting. will remove once it becomes more readable.